# How to get text seperated by br elements in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to get the list of violations from the following markup:

```
<b><font size="2" face="Verdana">Violations:</font></b><br>
<i><font size="2" face="Verdana">A summary of the violations found during the inspection are listed below.</font></i><br>
<br>
<font size="2" face="Verdana">209    Food not protected from contamination [s. 12(a)] <br>
<br>
 302 *Critical*  Equipment/utensils/food contact surfaces not properly washed and sanitized [s. 17(2)] <br>
<br>
 306    Food premises not maintained in a sanitary condition [s. 17(1)] <br>
<br>
</font><br>
```

Any idea on how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem

`<dd itemprop="Address">Schwimmschulkai xx<br>80xx Gxx<br>Gxx<br>Stxx</dd>`

and solved it like this:

`response.css('dd[itemprop="Address"]::text').getall()`

output:

`['Schwimmschulkai xx', '80xx Gxx', 'Gxx', 'Stxx']`

Feel free to adapt this solution to your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
response.xpath('string(//font)').extract()
```

UPD:
Use selector `response.xpath("string(//font[5])").extract()` if you parse this page http://www.healthspace.ca/Clients/FHA/FHA_Website.nsf/0/ABD0FA785D27B11588257C6900050EA3?OpenDocument

Comment: That gives me all the font elements in the document. I have tried '//font[text()="Violations:"]/following::font' but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you get me webpage url?